# Can a subscription in Azure Service Bus pick up messages previously brokered?

Tags: azure, subscriptions, azureservicebus

I've got this Service Bus which has messages in it already. 
Currently I'm creating subscriptions with a SqlFilter - let's say the filter is (myProperty < x).

The problem is that I don't know what x is until the messages are already in the queue. 
When I have a concrete value for x and make a new subscription (myProperty < 123) I can't use it to receive messages which are already in the queue.

Is there some way to flag a subscription to obtain messages which were in the queue before the subscription was created? I suspect I'll need to switch to a table instead of a bus?

Answer (score 0):

Messages are filtered when they are received, so a new subscription will not be able to pick up previous messages. A table would probably be best to persist the messages if you want to process them at a later time.

Edit: With version 1.8 of the SDK, you can chain together topics -- so you might be able to create a new topic for the subscription, and send the messages in the existing topic to the new topic. Although that would duplicate messages, it would solve your problem using topics / subscriptions. Watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Service-Bus-Tutorials/Windows-Azure-SDK-18-Updates-for-Service-Bus) to learn more about the updates for Azure SDK 1.8.